# How to apply an aspect to a predefined class?

Tags: postsharp

I am new to AOP and PostSharp. I am trying to apply an aspect to a predefined class, for example the System.Windows.Forms.Button class and intercept some of its methods.
Can you guide me how to do that with PostSharp? Can we use PostSharp to capture event raised from a given type of UIElement?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

MethodInterceptionAspect works on methods declared in external DLL's by intercepting the call on call site. That means that the method itself is not transformed and instead the place where you call the method is changed. The original assembly is not transformed.

You can do this by multicasting the attribute on your assembly and explicitly specifying `AttributeTargetAssemblies`:

```
[assembly:MyAspect(AttributeTargetAssemblies="myassembly,...", AttributeTargetTypes="...", AttributeTargetMembers="..."]
```

This implies few limitations. For example if the code is called from external code, the call will not get intercepted. In your case you could use this to intercept a method that is always called from the designer code (like `this.Controls.Add(...)`).

In case of buttons in your source code I think there will be a different viable approach. If you create `LocationInterceptionAspect` and multicast it on all fields of type `Button`, you will be able to intercept creation of all buttons in your application. In the aspect code (set handler), you can then register to the `Clicked` event of those buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt thats possible since i dont think ilweaving step of postsharp can manipulate already compiled external dlls.

What you can do is implement your own button (extend from button) and have those methods intercepted

Comment: It is not efficient since I have to wrap all UI elements just to capture their events:(

Comment: For events, what do you want to do? Wouldn't a regular event handler work?

Comment: I just want to know when a button is clicked, for all buttons in the program.